# Azure app service 502.5 error with .NET Core 2.1 app with Angular

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have my front end app developed in Angular having .NET Core 2.1. The project is created with Angular and .NET Core template. All of the front end is developed using Angular and .NET core functionality is not use specifically so it just has SampleDataController.cs.

The site has been deployed to Azure App Service since few years. But we are now getting error as:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure.

On checking event log we see:

> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/AppName' with physical root
> 'C:\home\site\wwwroot' failed to start process with commandline
> 'dotnet .\DLLName.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005' : 8000808c.

The same code and configuration is working fine in other Azure Web Apps. I checked some similar questions and tried deleting wwwroot folder, changing between 32 and 64 bit but it is not working.

I created a deployment slot and deployed the same code and then swapped the deployment slot to the production. This new slot is working fine. But the original slot is giving error.

Is there any change from Azure platform due to which app started giving error? How can I resolve this error? Any pointers would be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/runtime-store#aspnet-core-implicit-store-net-core-20-only) add `<PropertyGroup>
  <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>`  in your `.csproj` and check once

Comment: @Harshitha, Document mentions (.NET Core 2.0 only) so may not work as my app is on .NET Core 2.1.

Comment: This issue popped up on an Azure Web app we have not published to/edited/reconfigured in over 2 years. Yesterday (Sept 5) it suddenly has this 502.5 error too.

Comment: We noticed this TODAY on a legacy (rarely used) app service.  All of a sudden we have 502.5, WTH Azure?

Comment: @DeannaD did you find a solution, i also have a legacy project that suddenly crashed yesterday. Tried the manifest propGroup fix, tried changing target architecture. Nothing seems to work

Comment: Update: I fixed my issue by changing the platform to 64bit in my Azure Web App - Configuration under General Settings